# En edición de datos no puedo almacenar decimales NET.Core 6

Tags: jquery, .net-core

Tengo un proyecto en NET.6 que al intentar almacenar números con decimales me da error. El error que me da al intentar almacenar el valor con decimales es: The field Valoración terrenos (€): must be a number. Esto pasa al introducir, por ejemplo, '1672350,52'. Si en vez de coma pongo punto no me da error, pero no me guarda los decimales, me guarda, siguiendo el ejemplo anterior, 167235052.

En la base de datos el tipo de campo actual en money, pero lo he probado con numeric(18,2) y float y el resultado es el mismo.

Me ha parecido leer por algún foro que el problema es de jquery, pero no he visto nada.

¿Cómo se puede hacer para que almacene el valor numérico con decimales?

Gracias.

Modelo:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Valoración terrenos (€):", Description = "Valoración terrenos (€)", Prompt = "Valoración terrenos (€)")]                
        public decimal ValorTerrenos { get; set; }
```

Vista:

```
<dt class="col-sm-2">
 <label asp-for="ValorTerrenos" class="control-label"></label>                                </dt>
<dd class="col-sm-10">
 <input asp-for="ValorTerrenos" asp-is-invariant="true" class="form-control" />
 <span asp-validation-for="ValorTerrenos" class="text-danger"></span>
</dd>
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado cómo está la columna donde guardas esa información en la base de datos?

Comment: Si, es numérica y acepta decimales. Como pongo mas adelante el problema está en la validación en la parte del cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Después de darle muchas vueltas y probar varias opciones en la página que pongo a continuación encontré la respuesta. Yo apliqué la opción 3. Un saludo.

https://www.variablenotfound.com/2011/04/aspnet-mvc-3-y-la-coma-en-los-decimales.html

Opción seleccionada:

3. Modificar la forma en que jQuery Validate parsea los decimales
   Afortunadamente, el plugin de validación para jQuery es muy flexible, y permite introducir código personalizado para la validación de formato numérico y comprobación de rangos, lo que nos brinda la posibilidad de solucionar nuestro problema de forma muy limpia.

El siguiente código sería una primera aproximación a la solución del problema. Como podéis observar, simplemente introducimos en $.validator.methods.number y $.validator.methods.range las funciones que queremos utilizar para validar respectivamente los números y los rangos, reemplazando la coma por el punto antes de realizar la conversión con parseFloat():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        value = floatValue(value);
        return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(value);
    }
    $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
        value = floatValue(value);
        return this.optional(element) || (value >= param[0] && value <= param[1]);
    }
 
    function floatValue(value) {
        return parseFloat(value.replace(",", "."));
    }  
</script>
```

Si incluimos este script en la página cuando la cultura activa sea la nuestra (o cualquier otra que también utilice la coma para separar decimales), tendremos el problema solucionado.

Una fórmula más elegante y universal sería modificar la función floatValue(), y en lugar de reemplazar de forma manual los caracteres, utilizar el plugin Global para realizar la conversión a flotante según la cultura actual. Los detalles de esto, sin embargo, los dejo para otro post.

En fin, que como habréis comprobado existen mil y un enfoques posibles para enfrentarnos al problema. Espero que las ideas que hemos ido comentando os sean de utilidad para implementar vuestras propias soluciones hasta que tengamos una vía “oficial” para conseguirlo.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).